# Angular REST client ngResource can't get json

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ngresource

I have simple RESTful server with [`Flask`](https://flask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and I like to make a simple client with `AngularJS` using [`ngResource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource). The idea is make a GET to the server, and obtain a json file.

This is my `services.js`

```
var IpZapServices = angular.module('IpZapServices', ['ngResource']);
IpZapServices.factory('Plug', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:8003/api/plugs/:id',
             {id : "@id"}, {
                 query: {method: 'GET', params: {}, isArray: false}
           });
}]);
```

And the `controllers.js`

```
var IpZapControllers = angular.module('IpZapControllers', []);
IpZapControllers.controller('PlugListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Plug', function($scope, Plug) {
    $scope.plugs = Plug.query();
    console.log($scope.plugs);
}]);
```

But, I don't get the json file, get this:

```
Object { $promise: Object, $resolved: false }
```

Why? What's I do wrong? Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is the raw response that I receipt from the server.

```
{"plugs": [
    {"alarm": [],
     "id": 0,
     "name": "Plug 0",
     "state": false},
    .
    .
    .
    {"alarm": [],
     "id": 3,
     "name": "Plug 3",
     "state": false}
]}
```

**EDIT 2: Solution**

The problem is in the server. Simply add to the server [Flask-CORS](https://github.com/wcdolphin/flask-cors) and work!

```
from flask.ext.cors import CORS
app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

The solution is from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962699/flask-restful-cross-domain-issue-with-angular-put-options-methods#answer-27423922)

Comment: What does the Network tab of developer tools says? I would look the raw response that you receive

Answer (score 2):

You need to resolve the promise you have created with `Plug.query()`

Try this:

```
Plug.query().$promise.then(function (response) {
     console.log(response)
     $scope.plugs = response;
});
```

More information on this can be found in the docs on angularjs.org:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I have this error in the console: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8003/api/plugs. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).` whats I can do?

Comment: This means you have to send CORS Headers from the backend serving the API. Have a look into this: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var IpZapControllers = angular.module('IpZapControllers', []);
IpZapControllers.controller('PlugListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Plug', function($scope, Plug) {
  $scope.plugs = Plug.query();
  $scope.plugs.$promise.then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      $scope.plugs = result;
  });
}]);
```

Explanation:

Your call to `query` will not return the data immediately. It instead returns a promise object that will eventually get your data once the HTTP request is complete (notice that the console message said `resolved: false`).

Read More:

[Promises in AngularJS, Explained as a Cartoon](http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html)

Comment: I have this error in the console: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8003/api/plugs. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).` whats I can do?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have a promise there.

Don't assign the return value of the function, you need to wait till the promise resolves or rejects

Try

```
Plug.query().$promise
    .then(function (response) {
         // success code here
     }) 
    .catch(function (err) {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Whwn connecting to a webapi from the controller, use the success and error promise from the method call.

```
Ctrl.$inject = ["$scope", "Service"];
function Ctrl($scope, Service) {

    Service.getJson().success(function (data) {
        $scope.json = data;
    })
    .error(function (data) {
        // data should show the error
    });
}
```